# Swift How do I filter array based on another array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array `VIPArray` and `AddressArray` so I would like to filter `AddressArray` based on `VIPArray`. How can I do this?

`VIPArray` looks like this

```
let VIPArray = [["name": "John B"], ["name": "Sara K"]]
```

`AddressArray` looks like this

```
let AddressArray = [Address(name: "John B",  imageURL: "johnb", address: "178 Main St."),
                    Address(name: "Dave H",  imageURL: "daveh", address: "1011 Victoria St.."),
                    Address(name: "Sara K",  imageURL: "sarak", address: "279 Maple Av."),
                    Address(name: "Niles K", imageURL: "nilesk", address: "45 King St."),
                    Address(name: "Ingrid G",  imageURL: "ingridg", address: "33 Union St.")
```

So I would like to get this result: (filtered AddressArray)

```
[
    Address(name: "John B",  imageURL: "johnb", address: "178 Main St."),
    Address(name: "Sara K",  imageURL: "sarak", address: "279 Maple Av.")
]
```

Comment: This is simple, and your question is completely open-ended ("please write my entire code for me"). Be specific. What part don't you know how to do? Show your code so far and explain what the issue is. Demonstrate that you've made an honest try.

Comment: `VIPArray` is it array of arrays or array of dictionaries?

Comment: VIPArray is an array but AddressArray is array of dictionary and that's why I'm stuck.

Comment: Matt, I did try so many different filter solutions that I'm lost. Nothing worked for me and that is why I did not post anything. I did search and search every possible solutions and most of them I try but not even close. This is my last resort. Sorry.

Comment: Is your `VIPArray` really an `[[String]]`?  You can option-click on the variable name to check.

Comment: Hi vacawama, yes it is an [String]

Answer (score 4):

```
struct Address {
    var name: String
    var imageURL: String
    var address: String
}

let VIPArray = [["name": "John B"], ["name": "Sara K"]]

let AddressArray = [Address(name: "John B",  imageURL: "johnb", address: "178 Main St."),
                    Address(name: "Dave H",  imageURL: "daveh", address: "1011 Victoria St.."),
                    Address(name: "Sara K",  imageURL: "sarak", address: "279 Maple Av."),
                    Address(name: "Niles K", imageURL: "nilesk", address: "45 King St."),
                    Address(name: "Ingrid G",  imageURL: "ingridg", address: "33 Union St.")]


var filtered = [Address]()

for element in VIPArray {
    for address in AddressArray {
        if element["name"] == address.name {
            filtered.append(address)
        }
    }
}

for record in filtered {
    print(record)
}
```

OUTPUT:

Address(name: "John B", imageURL: "johnb", address: "178 Main St.")

Address(name: "Sara K", imageURL: "sarak", address: "279 Maple Av.")

Or:

```
let filtered: [Address] = AddressArray.filter { (address) -> Bool in
    for vip in VIPArray {
        if vip["name"] == address.name {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let VIPArray = [["name": "John B"], ["name": "Sara K"]]

struct Address {
    let name: String
    let imageURL: String
    let address: String
}

let addressArray = [Address(name: "John B",  imageURL: "johnb", address: "178 Main St."),
                    Address(name: "Dave H",  imageURL: "daveh", address: "1011 Victoria St.."),
                    Address(name: "Sara K",  imageURL: "sarak", address: "279 Maple Av."),
                    Address(name: "Niles K", imageURL: "nilesk", address: "45 King St."),
                    Address(name: "Ingrid G",  imageURL: "ingridg", address: "33 Union St.")]

let myVips = addressArray.filter() {VIPArray.contains(["name":$0.name])}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** You can simply use a `for-in loop` and `filter` to get the expected values:

```
    for VIP in VIPArray
    {
        let result = AddressArray.filter({ $0.name == VIP["name"] })
        print(result)
    }
```

**2.** Or you can use a combination of `map` and `filter` to get the expected values.

```
    let result = VIPArray.map { (VIP) -> Address? in
        if let address = AddressArray.filter({ $0.name == VIP["name"] }).first
        {
                return address
        }
        return nil
    }
    print(result)
```

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: I also tried this but I'm getting the same error Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: What is the type of `VIPArray` and `AddressArray`?

Comment: let result = VIPArray.map { (VIP) -> Address? in
        if let address = AddressArray.filter({ $0.name == VIP["name"] }).first
        {
                return address
        }
        return nil
    }
    print(result)

Comment: Sure. Accept the answer if you got it working. Happy coding 